# How to run a new process using linux address space switch?

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel

I am trying to start a new program (process) from the current c program that is running. Instead of using using fork() and exec() functions, I wanted to use linux kernel functions like switch_mm()/activate_mm() or copy_mm() etc.

What I have in mind is to first create a new address space in memory and load the new executable (ELF) to memory. Then do an address space switch from the current address space to  the new address space using a command like switch_mm() or activate_mm() and let the new program to start executing. I'm not sure if this is the correct correct approach. But, I think there are linux kernel functions that can be used to perform these tasks. I am not sure how to create a new address space in the current process and loading an ELF. I'm also not sure whether it is possible to accomplish this task with a single process (not creating a new process for the new program). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `switch_mm()`, etc are kernel functions.  User space can not use them directly.  `fork()`, etc will call them for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The functions you are referring to (`switch_mm()`, `activate_mm()`, `copy_mm()`) are all internal kernel functions, and are not available to userspace.

If you're feeling really adventurous, you *might* be able to simulate the effects of `fork()`/`exec()` by using the [`clone()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) system call to create a new process, then stopping the child process, modifying its state using [`ptrace()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace), then allowing it to continue. This will be a rather complex task, though.